# how to set the margin for a inner div without using padding/margin

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="out">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

In the above code, `out` div must be set with:

```
padding:0;
margin:0;
```

Then I want the inner div take all the place of the `out` with a certain margin.

[This is the effect I want](http://jsfiddle.net/rrMjj/)

In the exmaple,I position the inner div with `top,bottom,left,right` attributes,however it is not supported in ie6.

How to make it work cross-browser?

BTW,I do not want to use the absolute size like

```
height:1px
width:1px;
```

Comment: Only 6 percent of the people in the world use IE6. Please don't be one of them. ie6countdown.com/educate-others.aspx.

Comment: That's true,but our clients require we support ie6.

Comment: Then I would be charging more, good luck nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is changing `out`'s padding definitely not allowed? It would be very easy if you can: http://jsfiddle.net/rrMjj/2/

Comment: Yes,we can not change the `padding` for `out`

Comment: I am sorry but you use the absolute size for `inner` with `height:380px` which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Use this css

```
.inner{
border: 10px solid red;
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
background-color:gray;
}
```

[Link DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rrMjj/5/)